# Add users' network ID to the API shallow_user object

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam, api

A while ago, [Tim Post started an initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273512/262823) to improve spam protection on SE. One improvement that was almost immediately suggested was to [add network IDs to the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273495/a-centrallised-multi-site-community-controlled-globbing-blacklist/273512#comment888896_273512)'s `shallow_user` object.

Doing this would allow existing tools such as [SmokeDetector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) to better pick up on network spammers, which would in turn give users the tools they need to react to spam fast and get it out of all our faces.

Now while that's not an improvement on the network level, because spam still gets through, it does improve the protections we have in place *after* spam is posted by a significant amount. It would help catch spammers who do [things like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277485/implement-cross-site-posting-rate-limits-to-slow-down-spammers), as well as discourage the *miniscule* number of spammers who have any degree of common sense from posting at all.

This fruit seems like it's hanging as low as it gets; now that we've got an official feature request, can we get this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a long time coming but we have added `account_id` to the [`shallow_user`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) object. Enjoy!